# Merge TypeScript files into multiple output files in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

imagine a structure like this

```
/Scripts
- Logic1.ts
- Logic2.ts
- Common.ts
```

As a result I want to have Logic1.js and Logic2.js, but both should contain the output of Common.ts

I know the TypeScript compiler of Visual Studio can combine multiple .ts files into one single .js output file, but this is not what I need. I need to have certain .js output files which are a combination of a set of .ts files.
Can this be achieved without third party tools like "Bundler & Minifier"?

Comment: Yeah, just compile Logic1 and Logic2 separately.

Comment: How to do this?